# Laravelでのスクレイピング

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping

テスト等ではなく、データ採集を目的とするスクレイピングでは、PHP、Laravelにおいてどのツールが最も適しているのでしょうか。ちなみに実行速度を重視したいです。

Answer (score 1):

情報量の多さとパッケージ製作者などを考えると [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) で良いんじゃないでしょうか。

実行速度についてはキリがないですし、Goutte でも十分かとは思いますが、それでも妥協したくないのであれば、[cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/ref.curl.php) や [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/class.domdocument.php) などを組み合わせて使う手もあります。この場合パッケージの依存が減らせるのでスッキリはしますが、慣れてないと細かな実装部分で苦労すると思います。

また、外部へのリクエスト/レスポンスを cURL にまかせて、スクレイピング部分を Symfony の [DomCrawler](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler) でやるのもありかなと。いろいろ試して、自分にあったものを見つけてください :)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Goutte、参考にさせていただきます。現在はseleniumで稼働中なので、後々Goutteの実装への変更を検討したいと思います。